# Existence of eigenvalues and eigenvalues of infinite multiplicity in geometrically finite manifolds with infinite volume

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, eigenvalues

In the paper, The geometry and spectra of hyperbolic manifolds https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02830802 by PETER D HISLOP, the author sketched a proof for the following theorem: 
Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete, torsion-free, geometrically finite subgroup of hyperbolic isometries of $H^n$. Let $M/= H^n/F$ be the corresponding hyperbolic manifold with Laplacian $\Delta_{\Gamma}$. Assume that $M$ is non-compact. There are two cases.

(1) Vol$< \infty$. $\sigma_{ess}(\Delta_{\Gamma}) = \sigma_{ac}(\Delta_{\Gamma}) = [((n - 1)/ 2)^2, \infty)$, with finitely-many eigenvalues of
finite multiplicity in $[0,(n-1)/2)^2)$. There are examples for which there are
infinitely-many eigenvalues in $[((n - 1)/2)^ 2, \infty)$.

(2) Vol = $\infty$. $\sigma_{ess}(\Delta_{\Gamma}) = \sigma_{ac}(\Delta_{\Gamma}) = [((n - 1)/ 2)^2, \infty)$ with no embedded eigenvalues.
There are at most finitely-many eigenvalues of finite multiplicity in $[0, ((n - 1)/2)^2 )$.

Here $\sigma_{ess}$ denotes the essential spectrum. While reading the statements, I have the following questions concerning the infinite volume case, and unable to find reference online.

(1) The author did not talk about whether the eigenvalues in the infinite volume case have finite multiplicity or not. Do we have examples of infinite volume geometrically finite manifolds some of whose eigenvalues have infinite multiplicity?

(2) We have at most finitely many eigenvalues. Do we have an upper bound on the number of eigenvalues in this case? Are there examples of such manifolds without eigenvalues at all?

(3) Could the theorem be generalized to the case of pinched negatively curved case? I am not an analyst, and this question may be trivial.

Thank you for reading.